# Unresolved dependency on org.scalaz.stream in Play Framework 2.4.3

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

When trying to create a new Scala (v2.11) Play (v2.4.3) project in IntelliJ 15.0.1 I get the following exception:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalaz.stream#scalaz-stream_2.11;0.7a: not found
```

I see this in sbt.last.log:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.scalaz.stream#scalaz-stream_2.11;0.7a
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\brian\.ivy2\local\org.scalaz.stream\scalaz-stream_2.11\0.7a\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaz/stream/scalaz-stream_2.11/0.7a/scalaz-stream_2.11-0.7a.pom
```

IntelliJ Scala plugin version is 2.0.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve the dependency add the following line to build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Scalaz Bintray Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

Comment: Thank you!  Just what I needed.